# Selenium WebDriver + PhantomJS + Python - Execute Script and Handle Dialog Box

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I'm fairly new to coding, so forgive me if this is a dumb question:

I'm trying to get data from a list that is populated by executing a JavaScript, here's the relevant HTML section:

```
<a data-popover-ui="524151" data-popover-type="Search" href="javascript:LoadLists('SaveListSearchDetails.aspx?AutoLoad=1&amp;SavedListID=EID77FF7H&amp;SavedListTypeID=Search')" data-original-title="" title=""><span class="grid-result no-break">AVEV HRC FEC Master File</span></a>
```

After clicking this hyperlink, there's a dialog box that asks for confirmation

Here's what I tried:

```
browser = selenium.webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=r"E:\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\bin\phantomjs.exe")

browser.get('~~link where the javascript is~~')

first_list = browser.execute_script("LoadLists('SaveListSearchDetails.aspx?AutoLoad=1&amp;SavedListID=EID77FF7H&amp;SavedListTypeID=Search')"

browser.get('~~link where the list is~~')

browser.get_screenshot_as_file

browser.save_screenshot('1.jpg')
```

The screenshot is there for me to see if it worked quickly. The list is not being updated. I have almost no clue about java coding, so I'm not sure at all about what's going on, but I think it's because when the JavaScript is being executed, I'm not dealing with the dialog box that shows up.

I guess I could use get_element_by_SOMETHING, but I'm not sure which to use, since there's no ID in that HTML section, and I still need help with handling the damn dialog box.

Thanks yoooo

---

PhantomJS was not working. Switched to Chrome as the WebDriver.

```
t_list = find_element_by_link_text("~~text~~")
t_list.click()
time.sleep(5)
Alert(browser).accept()
```

Answer (score 0):

well you probably need to give a delay in or after execute script so that list loads up ( provided it loads in normal browser ).

Comment: A simple time.sleep() didn't work, even waiting 5 minutes (way more than it takes loading in the browser). Also, if understand your comment correctly, the list doesn't change when I access it in the browser after running the code.

Comment: not sure about java , but python has find_element_by_id , find_element_by_name , find_element_by_xpath etc. am sure java must be having similar ones. you can use web inspector / firebug to find id or xpath.

Comment: I'm using Python, and I know there's find_element_by_ but I don't know which one to use in this particular case. I'm not totally sure on what are xpath and css selectors, which may be the ones to be used

Comment: not getting you. all browsers have web developers ( if not install firebug add-on ) right click on any element and inspect.